# Convert a list from html into xml format

Tags: c#, html, xml, console-application

I am trying to convert a html list to xml format with a console application, but i did what i planned and now i dont know how to continue. I will share my code and explain a bit. What i dont know for now , and is confusing me is where the 'magic' happens. Ok i know i have to take that list from the page , read the list with all the tags inside, but what next, how can i transform that list into xml format? I am new to xml i know some basics so please help me.

Here is the application :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string _url = "http://example.com/media";

    int newsCounter = 0;
    List<News> _newsList = new List<News>();

    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(_url);
    HtmlNode ulNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@class='content articles']");

    HtmlNodeCollection liNode = ulNode.SelectNodes(".//li");
    foreach (HtmlNode node in ulNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='article_box']"))
    {
        var news = new News();

        news.Imgsrc = node.FirstChild.SelectSingleNode("//img").Attributes["src"].Value;

        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.FirstChild.SelectNodes("//img[@src]"); 

        foreach (HtmlNode childNode in node.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='box_info']"))
        {
           // string src = node.SelectSingleNode("//img").Attributes["src"].Value;

            foreach(HtmlNode _node in childNode.SelectNodes(".//h3"))
            {
                news.Link = "";
                news.Title = _node.FirstChild.InnerText;
                news.Date = _node.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText;
                news.Text = _node.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText;
            }
        }

        _newsList.Add(news);
        newsCounter++;

    }
```

and also the News class :

```
public class News
{
    public string Imgsrc { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Link { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

these are all the parameters i have to read from the list.I am able to read them and return all of the news in my list , but what next , how to transform my list into xml format? Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Well, the simplest, now that you have that code, would be to mark `News` as `Serializable` and then use `XmlSerializer` to export it. Might have been easier to just build the XML as you go using `XmlDocument` or LINQ to XML.

Comment: I agree with Mike... no need for the intermediate list. Just build your XML directly as you go with XDocument.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way of creating xml.  There are not a lot of items in your case so just using Xml linq is very simple.  Putting it into a class may produce cleaner code or you can just use the code directly like Sledge suggested.

```css
    public class News
    {
        public string Imgsrc { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Link { get; set; }

        public string Date { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public XElement ToXml()
        {
            return new XElement("news", new object[] {
                new XElement("Imgscr", Imgsrc),
                new XElement("Title", Title),
                new XElement("Link", Link),
                new XElement("Date", Date),
                new XElement("Text", Text),
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone guys. I marked 'News' class as Serializable and with a few lines of code managed to generate the xml file. Here is the code, really simple :

```
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<News>));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\News.xml"))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, _newsList);
        }
```